# Insert counter for macro name tracking vba

Tags: excel, vba, counter

> How to make commandButton1..5 names executable within a loop from a
> single Sub_Click routine??
> Added the 5 macros i need to use with Active X buttons.
> The macros are navigation references in the active sheet "GANTT".
>
> ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

```
Sub Att_1()
'
' Att_1 Macro
'
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Sheets("GANTT").Unprotect
  Sheets("LISTE").Unprotect
    Sheets("LISTE").Select
    Range("E3").Select
    Sheets("LISTE").Protect
     Application.Goto Reference:= _
 "offset(INDEX(GANTT!R[3]C[7]:R[3]C[496],MATCH(1,IF(GANTT!R[3]C[7]:R[3]C[496]<>"""",IF(GANTT!R[3]C[7]:R[3]C[496]<>""I"",1)),0)),-1,-2)", Scroll:=True

End Sub
Sub Att_2()
'
'  Att_2 Macro

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Sheets("GANTT").Unprotect
 Sheets("LISTE").Unprotect
   Sheets("LISTE").Select
   Range("E4").Select
    Sheets("LISTE").Protect
    Application.Goto Reference:= _
 "offset(INDEX(GANTT!R[3]C[7]:R[3]C[496],MATCH(1,IF(GANTT!R[3]C[7]:R[3]C[496]<>"""",IF(GANTT!R[3]C[7]:R[3]C[496]<>""I"",1)),0)),-2,-2)", Scroll:=True
End Sub

Sub Att_3()
'
' Att_3 Macro
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Sheets("GANTT").Unprotect
  Sheets("LISTE").Unprotect
    Sheets("LISTE").Select
    Range("E5").Select
    Sheets("LISTE").Protect
    Application.Goto Reference:= _
 "offset(INDEX(GANTT!R[3]C[7]:R[3]C[496],MATCH(1,IF(GANTT!R[3]C[7]:R[3]C[496]<>"""",IF(GANTT!R[3]C[7]:R[3]C[496]<>""I"",1)),0)),-3,-2)", Scroll:=True
End Sub
Sub Att_4()
'
' Att_4 Macro
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Sheets("GANTT").Unprotect
  Sheets("LISTE").Unprotect
    Sheets("LISTE").Select
    Range("E6").Select
    Sheets("LISTE").Protect
    Application.Goto Reference:= _
  "offset(INDEX(GANTT!R[3]C[7]:R[3]C[496],MATCH(1,IF(GANTT!R[3]C[7]:R[3]C[496]<>"""",IF(GANTT!R[3]C[7]:R[3]C[496]<>""I"",1)),0)),-4,-2)", Scroll:=True
End Sub

Sub Att_5()
'
' Att_5 Macro
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Sheets("GANTT").Unprotect
  Sheets("LISTE").Unprotect
    Sheets("LISTE").Select
    Range("E7").Select
    Sheets("LISTE").Protect
    Application.Goto Reference:= _
   "offset(INDEX(GANTT!R[3]C[7]:R[3]C[496],MATCH(1,IF(GANTT!R[3]C[7]:R[3]C[496]<>"""",IF(GANTT!R[3]C[7]:R[3]C[496]<>""I"",1)),0)),-5,-2)", Scroll:=True
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() '--> CALL MACRO
ActiveSheet.CommandButton1.BackColor = RGB(200, 330, 10)
Call Att_1
Sheets("GANTT").Protect
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()   '--> CALL MACRO
ActiveSheet.CommandButton2.BackColor = RGB(200, 330, 10)
Call Att_2
Sheets("GANTT").Protect
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click() '--> CALL MACRO
ActiveSheet.CommandButton3.BackColor = RGB(200, 330, 10)
Call Att_3
Sheets("GANTT").Protect
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click() '--> CALL MACRO
ActiveSheet.CommandButton4.BackColor = RGB(200, 330, 10)
Call Att_4
Sheets("GANTT").Protect
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click() '--> CALL MACRO
ActiveSheet.CommandButton5.BackColor = RGB(200, 330, 10)
Call Att_5
Sheets("GANTT").Protect
End Sub
```

Comment: Are these buttons on a Form or on a sheet? If on the sheet, what type are they? Form or ActiveX controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub CallButtonsClickEvent()
 Dim i As Long

 For i = 1 To 5
    Application.Run "" & ActiveSheet.CodeName & "" & ".CommandButton" & i & "_Click"
    'Application.Run "" & ActiveSheet.CodeName & "" & ".Att_" & i
    'Sheets("GANTT").Protect
 Next i
End Sub
```

Seeing your workbook, I commented the second and the third lines because they are included in the button Click event...

Comment: Hi, this is not working but i am looking something like this. I need to call a list of macros (Att_1...Att_5) from a list to command_buttons. I try to do this from a short routine cause that list can be extended in the future up to 200. Thank you.

Comment: @Theodoros kioumourtzis: You did not answer my clarification question... So, are we talking about **Sheet buttons, ActiveX type**? If not, what are you talking about? Then, your code example from the question, does not refer to what you are trying explaining now. Not exactly knowing what are you really need, nobody can help, I am afraid... So, can you edit your question, put there some such 'macros' to pe processed and we can talk again only after that. But, if you need my help, you should tag me somehow (@FaneDuru)...

Comment: @Theodoros kioumourtzis: I did not observe that the `Subs` named "Att_" followed by a number need to be also called by incrementing their ending number. Please, test the updated code. But firstly, please, try answering my clarification question...

Comment: Sorry! I updated my posted code + comments. Hope this is more clear. Tried your updated code in the main code and as a module but still not working.

Comment: @Theodoros kioumourtzis:  The above solution should work for the situation you are describing. If not something confidential, can you share the workbook you use? You can use a transfer site. [Here](https://easyupload.io/) is a free one and easy to be used. If something confidential, you can build a workbook with dummy data... Otherwise, I cannot understand why it does not work on your workbook and works on mine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the code is running fine! Please also check your email for an additional question.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you would want to complicate it with a loop... You can just call them all from another sub like this:

```
Private Sub Test()
    CommandButton1_Click
    CommandButton2_Click
    CommandButton3_Click
    CommandButton4_Click
    CommandButton5_Click
End Sub
```